# NSString and Japanese

Tags: xcode, unicode, nsstring, cjk

Does anyone know if NSString supports Japanese characters? I wrote something like this:

```
NSString* str = @"日本語";
```

But that displays only some letters and numbers in the XCode debugger. How can I write Japanese words in an iPhone app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems correct.

> But that displays only some letters and numbers in the Xcode debugger

I'm guessing the "letters and numbers" are something like \u123\092 etc.? What you are seeing in the debugger is the unicode equivalent. If you display the string in a UILabel or something like that, it will look fine.

Comment: To be more specific, if you're using NSString, then I can assume you are using iOS or OS X, where the default encoding locale is always UTF8.  NSString should be able to hold any sort of UTF8 text, but as mentioned by the answer, anything beyond ASCII may or may not be decoded in a friendly form in the debugger.